# How to distinguish between tree view item with same name and different parent in Coded UI for Desktop application

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Any help is much appreciated.

My tree structure in Window is :

```
-Main

  -Sub1

    -100 

-Main1

  -Sub1

    -101

-Main2
  -Sub1
    -103
-Main3
  -Sub2
    -104
```

When I try to write the code in coded ui:
It works fine for 
Main->Sub1->100
But It fails for 
Main1->Sub1->101 ==>It instead takes the path

Main1-> (Main-sub1)-> and is unable to find 101

Any suggestion is much appreciated.
I am reading the data from xml file and trying to select treview items in my Windows application and test it

Comment: what search properties are you using? how are you defining the controls? more information is needed

Comment: I am using uITreeItem1.SearchProperties[WinTreeItem.PropertyNames.Name] = s,

Comment: s is the name of the field in the menu, The problem is I am not able to keep track of parent elements

Comment: i think the error occurs when you pass Sub1 as the parent for 101 - the reason is that Sub1 parent is already set to Main. to avoid this you'll need to manage which control is passed as parent. are you using the recorder or writing the code by yourself?

Comment: I am writing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Your case when you are trying to build **sub1** with search properties use **main1** as parent. that will surely resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep, I tried your suggestion and it worked.